# Given all values except interest rate, how do I solve EMI formula for interest rate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The installment amount is calculated by the formula below.

[image]

I have a dataframe where I have the principal amount (P), installment amount and number of payments (n) in different columns and I wish to calculate the interest rate (i) for all rows.

| Principal (P) | Installment Amount | Number of Installments (n) | Interest Rate (i) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.300 | 187 | 35 | r |

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I find some hits that look promising when I search for "How do I calculate the interest rate if I know the EMI, tenure, and Principal".

Comment: See for example https://rinterested.github.io/statistics/newton_raphson_method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe called `df`

```
>>> df
    Principal  Installment  Num Payments
0      1000.0         40.0            30
1      3500.0        200.0            20
2  10000000.0    2000000.0            10
```

and a function `interest` using some solving method (in below example, [Newton-Raphson](https://rinterested.github.io/statistics/newton_raphson_method.html))

```py
ERROR_TOLERANCE = 1e-6

def interest(principal, installment, num_payments):
    def f(x):
        return principal * x**(num_payments + 1) - (principal + installment) * x**num_payments + installment
    def f_prime(x):
        return principal * (num_payments + 1) * x**num_payments - (principal + installment)*num_payments * x**(num_payments - 1)

    guess = 1 + (((installment * num_payments / principal) - 1)/12)
    intermediate = f(guess)
    while abs(intermediate) > ERROR_TOLERANCE:
        guess = guess - intermediate / f_prime(gues
        intermediate = f(guess)
    return guess
```

you can calculate the interest rate like

```py
df['Interest'] = df.apply(lambda row: interest(row['Principal'],row['Installment'],row['Num Payments']),axis=1)
```

giving

```py
>>> df
    Principal  Installment  Num Payments  Interest
0      1000.0         40.0            30  1.012191
1      3500.0        200.0            20  1.013069
2  10000000.0    2000000.0            10  1.150984
```

*Note*: tweak `ERROR_TOLERANCE` as desired to meet requirements.